# Strange behavior of dialogs in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, scroll, jquery-ui-dialog, centering

In my site I have been using many dialogs, and works fine. But last added has strange behavior. When I open dialog, dialog shows not centered on screen, but moved down- I must scroll down to see it.

I tried this code for centering dialog after open it:

```
$('#mydialog').dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      height:400,
      width:600,
      draggable: false,//solve another my problem with dialog
      modal: true,
      open: function(){
            $('#mydialog').position().left = 0;
            $('#mydialog').position().top = 0;
      ...
```

Also tried:

```
 position: 'top',
```

and

```
 position: 'center',
```

and

```
position: ['center', 'top'],
```

and

```
      open: function(){
            $(this).scrollTop();
```

Nothing center dialog on screen after open. I am using jQuery v1.9.1 and jQuery UI v1.10.3.

EDIT:
There is problem with positioning & relative-absolute. 
I tried this code:

```
      open: function(){
            var x= 0;
            var y= 0;
            $(this).dialog('option', 'position', [y, x]);
```

Position 0,0:
[image]
And just one scroll down with mouse wheel:
[image]

EDIT:
There is no problem with hidden element: `<input type='text' style='width: 0; height: 0; top: -100px; position: absolute;'/>` on beginning of html dialog. But if I remove this line, it cause another problem: [jQuery UI datepicker opens automatically within dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932420/jquery-ui-datepicker-opens-automatically-within-dialog) datepicker is automatically open after dialog is open

(important info: dialog open is after click on first column in row in table)

EDIT2:
There is cutted version of my website: 
http://users16.jabry.com/testingpurpose/ko.asp
I need to always centered dialog after click on link in frst column on last tab. AND after click, opened dialog may not have popup calendar minidialog.

EDIT 3:
image of my problem: http://is.gd/1Hn5p6

Comment: Tons of things that could be going wrong, but my gut says you're using a plugin that you didn't write yourself, that you haven't mentioned in your question...

Comment: If you provide a link to your site, or a jsfiddle, it'll be very helpful.

Comment: ok, there is cutted version of my website: 
(slow freehosting, be patient)
http://users16.jabry.com/testingpurpose/ko.asp

Comment: can you put the hidden element back on the page? Let's try to fix it in CSS only without touching the other functionality

Comment: There is no problem with comment/uncomment hide element... There is what you asking (uncomment it):
http://users16.jabry.com/testingpurpose/ko2.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue some time ago, basically when a dialog is initialized it will set focus to the first active form element, in your case the calendar.

A quick solution would be something like

```
open: function () {
    $("#id-calendar").blur(); //or
    $("#id-calendar").datepicker( "hide" ); 
}
```

Also, dialogs may have unexpected issues if you use them on the fly, like `$('<div></div>').dialog(...);`

If you load them from a remote content always do:
   `$('.div').html(contentHtml).dialog(...);`

Comment: I have only Default.asp (and query.asp for ajax post requests) and in this file I have dialog filled (html) with blank input edits. Just click on column- name Alex fill this dialog data from DB (ajax post request via query.asp). No dynamically remote calling.

Comment: There is img of my problem- still can't understand, how is it possible, that dialog is not centered- huge top position... http://is.gd/1Hn5p6 I am getting crazy with this issue (trying to find solution more than 7 days).

Comment: I found solution! Problem were in ajax post request- returned value (first table column) was in this format:
    `<a href='#' class='edit-...' `
and problem part was href="#" !!!

Thanks for all, bounty goes to Bruno Q. F. Cya

edit: please, mark this post as solution. thx

Answer (score 0):

If this is a popup of any sort, then the positioning logic to make it centered should be something pretty close to:

```
left: $('#parent').width / 2 - ($('#thing-to-center).width / 2);
top: $('#parent').height / 2 - ($('#thing-to-center).height / 2);
```

But if this is a plugin that you're not familiar with and the offset seems small and arbitrary, i'd pull up the browser console and use the inspector tool to find child elements with weird padding/margins that might be affecting your parent alignment.

Comment: I tried some new things- just edit my first question (begin of this topic). Please, look for it.

Comment: I found the hidden element:


<input type='text' style='width: 0; height: 0; top: -100px; position: absolute;'/>

on beginning of html dialog. But if I remove this line, it cause another problem:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/932420/jquery-ui-datepicker-opens-automatically-within-dialog

datepicker is automatically open after dialog is open